# Transfer data from one Form to anoter active Form through Visual basic6

Tags: vb6

I have total Four Form.I want to transfer one Form data to another active Form (means Form2 data to Form3 and Form2 Data to Form4) in visual basic6 code. But only Form3 show transfer Data.This is Form2 Code........

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

'suppose if we want to get data from Form2 and transfer to Form3

' if Form2 and Form3 is Active Form

If Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Form1" Or Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Form2" Or Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Form3" Then  

  Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To Form2.List1.ListCount - 1

Form3.List1.AddItem Form2.List1.List(i)

Next i

Form3.Show

Unload Me

'suppose if we want to get data from Form2 and transfer to Form4

' if Form2 and Form4 is Active Form


ElseIf Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Form1" Or Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Form2" Or Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Form4" Then   

  Dim j As Integer

For j = 0 To Form2.List1.ListCount - 1

Form4.List1.AddItem Form2.List1.List(j)

Next j

Form4.Show

Unload Me

End If

End Sub
```

please Help me for solving this issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your `If` statements. Your first statement says that if the current screen is Form1, Form2 or Form3, then transfer data from Form2 to Form3. Otherwise, if it's Form1, Form2 (which it won't be, right?) or Form4, then transfer data from Form2 to Form4.

So, what your logic says is that the only way that you'll transfer data to Form4 is if Form4 is the active form. From your comments, you're saying that you're pressing a "get data" button on Form3. When you do that, Form3 is the active form. That means that your first `If` condition is satisfied. In fact, the only time that it isn't satisfied is when Form4 is the active form.

You need to understand that this line of your code:

```
ElseIf Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Form1" Or Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Form2" Or Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Form4" Then
```

Does exactly the same thing as this:

```
ElseIf Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "Form4" Then
```

Which, since you only have four forms, does exactly the same thing as this:

```
Else
```

If you understand that, you'll see the reason you're having the problem, keeping in mind that your first `If` block only populates Form3.

Comment: Bob I have also try as you say but nothing only Form3 show result.Please help me

Comment: I have already mention above that i want to transfer data from Form2 to Form3 and Form4.So, Form 2 is already Active Form and Form3 and Form4 are none active form.When user press Form3 Get Data button then Form2 data transfer to Form3 and Form4.

Comment: @saif "When user press Form3 Get Data button then. . . " Form3 gets active and Form2 is no longer active.